# vector<X*>* versus vector<X>*

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, vector

Under what circumstances would it be better to use:

```
vector<X*>* vector = new vector<X>();
```

instead of:

```
vector<X>* vector = new vector<X>();
```

and what are the advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: Neither of those are particularly nice. I'd prefer a `std::vector<X>` if possible or a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>>` if necessary.

Comment: I'd say that you almost never want to do `new vector<...>`...

Comment: You probably want to assign a `new vector<X*>()` in the first example, right?

Comment: I agree with @chris and Oli. Since a `vector` already dynamically allocates its contents, why would you dynamically allocate the vector itself? I can't think of a single circumstance.

Comment: Easy rule: **If you don't know what the difference is, use neither**.

Comment: `vector<X*>* vec = new vector<X>()` will not compile.

Comment: @MarkRansom: you would dynamically allocate the vector if it needs dynamic storage duration (same as any other type). For example if it is shared between objects that themselves have dynamic storage duration. Still Oli is right, you shouldn't write `new vector` since we have `make_shared`. The significance of the fact that vector allocates its contents dynamically is just that it means a different reason for dynamically allocating objects ("too big to fit on the stack") never applies to vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's almost never a good reason to dynamically allocate the vector itself. Don't do that unless you're doing something very unusual.

In the common case that all the objects have the same type, then you'll usually want a vector of objects, `vector<X>`.

You would want a vector of pointers, `vector<X*>` if

- `X` is a polymorphic base class; and
- you want to access objects of different subtypes of `X` via the vector; and
- you don't need the container to manage object lifetimes for you.

If you want the container to manage the lifetimes of heterogeneous objects, then store smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`, or use something like the [Boost pointer container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) library.

As mentioned in the comments, you might also consider a vector of pointers if the objects can't or shouldn't be moved: vectors will move their elements as they grow, to maintain a contiguous array. In that case, you should also consider using a stable container like `deque` or `list`.

Comment: Another reason why you may need `vector<X*>` is when you don't want your objects to change addresses at each vector reallocation (this is important if other objects keep pointers to the objects you are storing).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yes, I thought about mentioning that. It's probably better to choose a stable container (`deque` or `list`) in that case; but maybe there are cases where an extra level of indirection is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all the same, as in the first case you store a pointer, and in the second case you store a value.

It's better to use a vector of pointers when you already have pointer, for example for objects allocated on the heap (using `new`).
In this case you can even use a vector of `std::unique_ptr`.

It's better to use a vector of values when you have the value of the object directly, or you'll have to make sure the object is not destroyed.

And I don't get why would you want to dynamically allocate the vector ? But as you did a for both cases, that's not the question.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer `vector<X>` unless you have a good reason not to.

`vector<X*>` should be used if the vector does not own the objects it is storing, or if you are obtaining pointers through some mechanism that you have no control over. It can also be more efficient if the objects are expensive to copy or move, but benchmark it first - the `vector<X>` will have better locality of reference. It has the big disadvantage that destroying the vector will *not* delete the contained pointers, making it bug-prone and not exception safe. Use `vector<unique_ptr<X>>` to fix that last problem.

Answer (score 0):

You never will want a pointer to a `vector`, just use a straight up `vector` and let it handle the memory management.  And you'll never want a `vector` of *raw* pointers, use some kind of smart pointer instead, like `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Raw pointers are kind of not en vogue in modern C++. Especially, when one can do without indirection all-together. For cases where you don't, smart pointers may be used. First of all, I wouldn't `new` the vector itself (I don't think I ever `new`ed any `std` type directly).

You may want to share a vector, then there might be situations, where there is a reason for having an indirection to a vector, but it'd look like this:

```
auto myVec = std::make_shared<std::vector<X>>();
// ^ -- that's an std::shared_ptr<std::vector<X>>
```

But I guess, that's not your question. You are after the content of the vector. There might be a good reason to have indirection to elements, for instance in some clever algorithms. But there I would also suggest to use smart pointers:

```
auto myVec = std::make_shared<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>>>();
myVec.push_back(std::make_shared<X>(xarg1,xarg2));
myVec.push_back(myVec.back());
```

Here you see that an individual item in the vector is tracked twice. If you want this for some reason (which is not as crazy as it sounds), use indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically creating a vector is the only option if you want to use the vector with a **custom allocator that is created dynamically**.

Regarding the X* Mike Seymour gives a good answer.